# Runtime error when using `mui-x-date-pickers` and `mui-x-data-grid`

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

I'm upgrading to MUI5. TS compiling passed but I got tons of console errors: `Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/unstable_composeClasses'` and `./node_modules/@mui/lab/node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/CalendarPicker/calendarPickerClasses.js Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/generateUtilityClass' in ...`

I have these in my `package.json` file

```
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.86",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.12.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
```

I don't know if this matters, my `tsconfig.json` has

```
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I added a `"@mui/system": "^5.8.4",` but still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar issue https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30907

I finally resolved this by removing the config from `webpack`.

Comment: same here, I remove the babel-loader webpack configuration of storybook and let it use the default